# How to Hide Object Files from Eclipse's Script Explorer

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclipse to develop C++ programs. In the script explorer, I see my .cpp, .h files along with .o (object) files. Is there a way to hide these .o files from the script explorer?

Update: Here is a [snapshot](http://flic.kr/p/9dh2bZ) of the script explorer and the files I want to hide from view.

Comment: I finally found the answer: http://wuhrr.wordpress.com/2011/01/26/hide-irrelevant-files-from-eclipses-script-explorer/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reference: http://wuhrr.wordpress.com/2011/01/26/hide-irrelevant-files-from-eclipses-script-explorer/

To create a resource filter:

In one of the navigation views, right-click the project or folder where you want to create the resource filter.
From the pop-up menu, select Properties. The properties dialog will open.
Expand the Resource section.
Click the Resource Filters section.
Click Add....
Specify the filter type, to what entries it applies to, and enter the condition.
Click OK.
Click OK.